# Is there a program that receives as input your drawing of a curve and outputs a parametric curve tracing it (reasonably close)?

Tags: parametric, visualization, parametrization

From what I know, B-Splines is the closest thing that we have to drawing curves and having them defined by the computer. I have some B-Spline code that does this interactively. However, those are a sequence of parametrics next to each other and they are often very cumbersome to work with. Is there anything better out there? Ideally, you'd like to be able to draw a reasonably simple curve by hand and have a program return its parametric representation, but perhaps that's too much to ask!

Comment: Wolfram Alpha's Image Analysis might do it. [This](http://www.researchgate.net/post/How_do_you_find_the_equation_of_a_curve_from_the_graph) is the closest I got from Google, though I didn't dig deep into the results.

Comment: @JessePFrancis Thx, I've been cruising about Wolfram's blogs, this is the closest I have found so far, using Fourier Series. I've asked this question because I want to define parametrics for a visualization of the Fourier Series I'm coding using epicycles.